# Representing special relativity on the hyperbolic plane

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, geometry

I recently gave a presentation on hyperbolic geometry and included mention that space-time is hyperbolic, but was not able to adequately explain what this means.

To demonstrate how space-time is hyperbolic, I want to plot the twin paradox on the hyperbolic plane.  So we will have two curves that move in the time dimension at the same rate.  One will not move through the x dimension, the other will move rapidly through the x dimension.

I understand that the hyperbolic plane is a gyrovector space, not a vector space, so $\hat i + \hat j \neq \hat j + \hat i$ and that's why people can age by different amounts.  I found a [web tool that has a nice projection of the hyperbolic plane](https://dmishin.github.io/hyperbolic-ca-simulator/index.html?grid=4,5&cells=4%7Bb246f31e-f196-4d5a-90af-bdc2dc4a9069%7D%7C1&generation=0&rule=B_3_S_2_7&viewbase=e&viewoffset=0:0:0), but I am still struggling to imagine this.  Could someone walk me through this or provide an alternative tool where I can plot equations on the hyperbolic plane (preferably animated).

[image: projection of squares on the hyperbolic plane, with 5 squares around each vertex]

My current understanding is that time is vertical on that projection which seems to imply that if you follow a straight line, space-time will rotate around you (i.e. your speed changes).

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Minkowski spacetime itself in not itself a hyperbolic space, but   4-velocity vectors $v^\mu =dx^\mu/d\tau$ have components that obey
$$
(v^0)^2-(v^1)^2-(v^2)^2-(v^3)^2=1, \quad v^0>0
$$
and so their tips lie on the upper half of a hyperboloid of two sheets embedded in Minkowski space  with metric
$$
(d\sigma)^2 = -(d\tau)^2=-(dx^0)^2+ (dx^1)^2+(dx^3)^2+(dx^3)^2.
$$
This embedded space, with its induced Rieimannian metric,  is a standard model of  3-dimensional (hyperbolic) Lobachevsky space.

Lorentz boosts on the velocity correpond to finite isometries of the  hyperbolic space.

Comment: Could you go down a dimension to the hyperbolic plane and draw an example on the diagram above?  I am struggling to understand why velocities are hyperbolic.

Comment: They are hyperbolic because the 4-vector with components $v^\mu dx^\mu/d\tau$ has normalization $g_{\mu\nu}(dx^\mu/\tau) (dx^\nu/d\tau) = (d\tau)^2/(d\tau^2)=1$.  If I plotted a velocity on your Poincare disc, it would be a dot (point).

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand the notation. If velocities are points, does that mean the gyrovector between two points represents the relative velocity?

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, but I am trying to visually see how special relativity can be represented on the hyperbolic plane.  E.g. If velocity is a point on the hyperbolic plane, does that mean that if you have two spaceships: A accelerates in the x direction, B accelerates in the y direction, then A accelerates in the y direction and B accelerates in the x direction (by equal amounts), the two spaceships are *not* traveling with the same velocity?

Comment: Exactly!  Even infinitesimal boosts in different directions do not commute: they differ by a rotation (Thomas precession) which is nothing but parallel transport on the negative-curvature hyperbolic space.

Answer (score 1):

Euclidean geometry is a flat (zero Riemann-curvature) space that uses [circular-]trigonometry (which uses the circle to measure angles).
Euclidean geometry is an affine space... so one can use vector methods.

Although it uses the circle to measure angles, we wouldn't describe Euclidean geometry as a spherical geometry.

Minkowski-spacetime geometry is a flat (zero Riemann-curvature) space that uses [hyperbolic-]trigonometry (which uses the hyperbola to measure rapidities).
Minkowski-spacetime geometry is an affine space... so one can use vector methods.

Although it uses the hyperbola to measure rapidity, we wouldn't describe Minkowskian-spacetime geometry as a hyperbolic geometry.

Hyperbolic geometry is a negatively-curved space.

It is not an affine space, so (as you suggest) can't use familiar vector methods.

Along the lines of @mikestone 's answer, the space of velocities (traced out by the tips of the 4-velocities) is a hyperbolic space.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting relativistic velocities $u_x u_y$ as coordinates inside the unit circle $u_{x}^{2}+u_{y}^{2}\leq1$ (with c=1), one can certainly see the relativistic velocity space can be modeled in terms of the [Poincaré disk model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) and the [Beltrami–Klein model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami%E2%80%93Klein_model) in hyperbolic geometry, since the unit circle is fundamental in those models as well.

However, there is a more direct (and probably less known) route to represent Minkowski space in terms of hyperbolic geometry: The [hyperboloid model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model) is directly based on the Lorentz/Minkowski quadratic form $$Q(x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n})=-x_{0}^{2}+x_{1}^{2}+\ldots+x_{n}^{2}=-1$$ from which it follows the the isometries of this model are directly given by the Lorentz group, including Lorentz boosts and rotations.

Indeed, using Lorentz transformations in terms of such models has a long history, which predates the development of special relativity, see [History of Lorentz transformations](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/History_of_Topics_in_Special_Relativity/Lorentz_transformation_(introduction)).